# I would like to know how facebook changes something you post like a weblink into a widget within the dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, frontend, backend

Does fb pick up on keywords? For example, if you try posting this link you will see that it displays "how to ask Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" and then the link at the bottom. Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

They query the link server-side, scrape it, and send that information to the browser as a widget.

You can watch it happen:

1. Copy a link to your clipboard.
2. Open Facebook.
3. Open your browser's Dev Tools and go to the Network tab.
4. Click in the Post box (so it loads the various things it loads when you do that).
5. Wait a few seconds.
6. In the Network tab, click Clear so you can see what's new.
7. Paste your link in the Post box.

You'll see a request for something like `https://www.facebook.com/react_composer/scraper/?composer_id=obscured&target_id=obscured&scrape_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F36964511%2Fi-would-like-to-know-how-facebook-changes-something-you-post-like-a-weblink-into&entry_point=obscured&source_attachment=obscured&av=obscured&dpr=1`. The response includes the information for the box.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks so much T.J.!! You are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses the [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/):

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any web page to have the same functionality as any other object on Facebook.

If you implement Open Graph metatags on your webpage Facebook will use these fields when creating the widget you see after posting a link.

For example, if you view the source of this page you'll see Open Graph tags for `og:image`, `og:title`, `og:description`, `og:type` and `og:url`. If you share this URL on Facebook, the widget will use the `og:title`, `og:description`, `og:image`, and `og:url`. You can view [this info](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F36964511%2Fi-would-like-to-know-how-facebook-changes-something-you-post-like-a-weblink-into) in Facebook's Open Graph Debugger tool.

A helpful tool is the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object), which allows you to post a URL and view how Facebook scrapes the page.